# ng-model is not updated as result of $http calling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to update ng-model value as result of $http.get call but it's not updated.

Here is my code.

**main.js**

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', ['$http', function($http) {
    var main = this;
    main.show = true;

    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'api url'    
    })
    .then(function(res) {
      main.show = true; 
      console.log('succeed call, main.show: ' + main.show);        
    }, function(res) {
      main.show = false;
      console.log('failed call, main.show: ' + main.show);
    });

    console.log('out of call, main.show: ' + main.show);
  }]);
```

**index.html**

```
...
<body ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl as main'>
  <a ng-show='main.show' href='/'>Succeed</a>
  <a ng-hide='main.show' href='/'>Failed</a>
</body>
...
```

**console log when api succeed**

```
out of call, main.show: true
succeed call, main.show: true
```

**console log when api failed**

```
out of call, main.show: true
failed call, main.show: false
```

My problem is the html always show me 'Succeed' link.

I tried many things even use `$timeout`, `$apply`, but it's also not working.

There are some answers for similar problems, but it was not working for me.

What should I do to solve the problem?

Comment: When api fails, why is it logging _succeed call,..._? As per the code, that should log _failed call_, is it?

Comment: Sorry. It was my mistake. I'll edit it.

Comment: Any error in console?

Comment: Yes. Any error in console.

Comment: I mean, are there any errors logged in the browser console. If yes, please post that error which you are getting.

Comment: There's no error in browser console.

Comment: @hshan Your demo works fine. see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42731410/3543808)

Comment: You can use ng-if="main.show" and ng-if="!main.show" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is working fine.

Try the below example. I deliberately pointed to the wrong URL so the service call will fail which will eventually goes into failure callback.

## Demo

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', ['$http', function($http) {
    var main = this;
    main.show = true;

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos1'
      })
      .then(function(success) {
        main.show = true;
        console.log('succeed call, main.show: ' + main.show);
      }, function(error) {
        main.show = false;
        console.log('failed call, main.show: ' + main.show);
      });

    console.log('out of call, main.show: ' + main.show);
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl as main'>
  <a ng-show='main.show' href='/'>Succeed</a>
  <a ng-hide='main.show' href='/'>Failed</a>
</body>
```

Comment: Right. It's my fault using $http with ng-init. Thanks for remind me.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are making your http calls are wrong.

First in the controller:

```
.controller('mainCtrl', ['$http', function($http) ...
```

In the controller first http should be passed as string: `'$http'`.

Asynchronous calls are made in the following way:

```
var promise = $http({
            method : 'POST',
            url : baseUrl,
            headers : {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            data : data
});

promise.then(function (response) {
        yourData = response.data;
        console.log(response.data);

        return yourData;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Something went terribly wrong.");
    });
```

Comment: Oops.. sorry. $http injection was my typo. I'll edit my question. And I edited my code using .catch but it's not working as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set main.show initial value to false

```
main.show =false;
```

Also define the ng-app value in HTML tag

Answer (score 0):

In the above code the console.log('out of call, main.show: ' + main.show); get printed before the http request gets executed and that is the reason why you always receive main.show = true. 
If you want access main.show then you should always do it after the http request succeeds or fails.

```
var main = this;

main.show = true;

$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'url'    
})
.then(function(res) {
  main.show = true; 
  console.log('succeed call, main.show: ' + main.show);        
}, function(res) {
  main.show = false;
  console.log('failed call, main.show: ' + main.show);
  DoSomething();

});
function DoSomething(){
    console.log('out of call, main.show: ' + main.show);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know.The console.log('out of call, main.show: ' + main.show); is just for testing. It's not related to result. Thanks for your answer.